# Why column widths are ignored?

Tags: html, css, html-table

Why does column widths are ignored here?

http://jsfiddle.net/dimskraft/M4Hn5/

```
<table class="menu">
    <colgroup>
        <col style="width:50%"/>
        <col style="width:50%"/>
    </colgroup>
    <tr>
        <td>ORION</td>
        <td>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Home</td>
                    <td>About</td>
                    <td>Subscribe</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

CSS

```
body {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, serif;
    color: darkgray;
    background-color: gray;
    font-size: 12px;
}
h1 {
    color: black;
    font-size: 14px;
}
table 
{
    width: 900px;
}
table.menu td {
    height: 100px;
    background-color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your CSS, you have `table { width: 900px; }`, but then in a TD you have an embedded table. This table is also being set to 900px, which is stretching its parent TD to be the entire width of the .menu table. Change that part of the CSS to `table.menu { width: 900px; }`